# Unable to display text of UILabel on UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel

I am unable to display a NSString into the UILabel. Below is part of the program shown, when the button is hit, those functions will be called.

This is the function that will be called by the UIAlert when the button is hit. It is in the Second View of a Navigation Controller. "location" is a NSString.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (buttonIndex == 0)
{       
    NSString *newString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:location];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:newString forKey:@"keyForLocation"];

    FirstViewController *newObject = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    [newObject updateCurrentLocationLabel:nil];
}
else {

}
```

}

This is in the header and implementation file of the View Controller of the Base View. Which is with the UILabel.

Header file

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *currentLocationLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *currentLocationLabel;
-(IBAction) updateCurrentLocationLabel:(id) sender;
```

Implementation file

```
- (IBAction) updateCurrentLocationLabel:(id) sender {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *myString1 = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyForLocation"];
    currentLocationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myString1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method, you're creating a new `FirstViewController` object that has nothing to do with the one that is (presumably) on your navigation stack.
You have to call the `updateCurrentLocationLabel` method on a view controller that is actually part of your view hierarchy. Just because you instantiate the same class doesn't mean you'll get the same object.

Comment: ok, so how do i solve the problem? any methods that i should use? i'm really sorry but im a newbie and i look for tutorials on this but there isn't one that is good out there.

Comment: `[(FirstViewController *)self.navigationController.topViewController updateCurrentLocationLabel:nil];` – But I recommend that you read some introductory material on object orientation and memory management. Any entry-level iOS book will do, your code shows that you haven't understood some very fundamental things yet.

Comment: ok, i had put NSLog statements at updateCurrentLocationLabel and the debugger consoler appears to have that statement, so can i assume that the program had when to the method? 

and yes! i'm reading up books again. clearly i don't understand some stuff.

Comment: Yes, your method was executed, but not by the correct object.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` first. Your defaults are not saved.

Comment: That's nonsense, you don't need to synchronize the user defaults every time you update a value, that happens automatically at periodic intervals. If the defaults haven't been written to disk yet, they will simply be read from memory.